# How I can open a project in browser when LiveReload don't go to the my project - ionic-framework

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-serve

When I generate a new folder in the ionic app, I call ionic serve, but it shows me `localhost:8100/tab1/tab1`. Then I delete `tab1/tab1` and write `/myApp/myApp`, but LiveReload again shows me `localhost:8100`, I tried, again and again, to write the path to my project, but it shows me again and again `localhost:8100`. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Try: `ionic serve --no-livereload`

Comment: Thank's! It very help to me